# How to delete particular field from Asset in Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

How can i delete particular field data from an Asset in from AssetRegistry of Hyperledger composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant delete nothing from Hyperledger, this is how blockchain works.

You need to update the asset with another value or empty value.
Or if you want to delete the field from all assets, then you should upgrade de peer with the new chaincode model.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanaGalla, accept the answer if it helped you.